# Page sequence in PDF-file

Tags: printing, libreoffice, pdf

Can I let Libre office create PDF-files with pages in a certain order? 
I am an amateur writer and produce books "in the kitchen" by printing the pages in a certain sequence so that they can be cut and glued. E.g I print now manually double sided pages with a two pages per side of the sheet: 1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4, etc up to about 100 but the print control window can only take a limited number of pages, hence I have to print in small batches. Creating a large PDF-file with a controlled page sequence would make life easier. A single PDF-file then would give me two printed copies simultaniously when cut to size A5 and glued.

Answer (score 1):

I have an alternative for you.
First install pdftk via software center or:

```
sudo apt-get install pdftk
```

then export the pdf normally in Libreoffice. Create 2 identical files, a.pdf and b.pdf, and run in a terminal in the directory where those files are stored:

```
pdftk A=a.pdf B=b.pdf shuffle A B output collated.pdf
```

This will create the file collated.pdf with 1,1,2,2,3,3 etc. which you can then print duplex.

If the terminal is not your thing (though it is extremely fast for what you are trying to do) there is also a GUI frontend for pdftk http://pdfchain.sourceforge.net/ (It is also in the repos).
However, I have never used the latter.